# how to get string 'Sugar&Jaggery, Salt' via <a> in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

plz anyone me i m beginner in codeigniter in herf passing url with string but the whole can't get in

controller & can't accepting as sting so what shold i do for it plz someone help me

//Here is html code which pass sting value

index.php/Home/product_show?type='Sugar&Jaggery , Salt'">Sugar & Jaggery , Salt

//controller get sting in type variable but on Sugur got not whole sting and pass type variable to model
public function product_show(){

$type = $_GET['type'];

```
die(var_dump($type));

 $data['testdata']= $this->Globle_model->get_multiple_record($type);

 $this->load->view('display_product',$data);
```

}

//model type variable check the subcategory from database and return to controller

public function get_multiple_record($type){

```
    $this->db->where_in('Subcategory_name',$type);
```

$get_data = $this->db->get('productmaster');

```
return $get_data->result_array();
```

}

//o/p
get this much of string(6) "'Sugar"

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below way to get all your string into the controller into
`$_GET['type']` variable.

1. Combine all your strings into a single variable using `_` into href

Example :

```
<a href="index.php/Home/product_show?type=Sugar_Jaggery_Salt">  Sugar & Jaggery , Salt </a>
```

2. In the controller, I have created one  `array()` with variable `subcategory_type` .In which key is coming from the view but its value from the database.

Example :

```
 function get_product_type(){
      $get_info = $this->input->get();
      $subcategory_type = array(
          "Sugar_Jaggery_Salt" => "Sugar&Jaggery , Salt"
      ); 
      $type_arr = $subcategory_type[$get_info['type']];
      $data['testdata']= $this->Globle_model->get_multiple_record($type_arr);
      $this->load->view('display_product',$data);
 }
```

3. In model,

   ```
    function get_multiple_record($type_array){
         $this->db->where_in('Subcategory_name',$type_array);
         $get_data = $this->db->get('productmaster');
         return $get_data->result_array();
    }
   ```

Try this and update me in case of anything.

Comment: yes, but subcategory_name in database is Sugar&Jaggery , Salt

Comment: I am going to edit answer using above subcategory.

Comment: Please check the new answer. Hope it will helps

Comment: yes, sir it will wrok thank u so much.But Subcategory_name not always this it will be dynamic like Cereals,Detergent Tools & accessory ,Sugar&Jaggery , Salt' etc, like this data in database so what should i do plz sugget getting in troble only because of this

Comment: I'm using ajax to pass value but the page not redirected to view. But it will show in Network (RESPONSE)

Comment: If these are dynamic values so i am sure it must be coming from the database in  that case you can get value id of that detergent tools and that should be store into the  productmaster table. so whenever value of detergent tools will be changed it won't affect your developed code.

Comment: thank u sir,but i resolve it temporary that issues using LIKE query.

Comment: and now i m working on add to cart product with session